# Appending to a container

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a doubt regarding the generic algorithm `copy` in C++.

To copy from destination container `ret` and source container `bottom`,

```
copy(bottom.begin(), bottom.end(), back_inserter(ret));
```

works but

```
copy(bottom.begin(), bottom.end(), ret.end());
```

does not. Do these two statements have different implications?

Comment: Yes, `copy` overwrites. You can't overwrite something that doesn't exist.

Comment: how do back_inserter(ret) and ret.end() differ?

Comment: @ichramm `back_inserter` is not a functor.  It is a function returning an iterator.  An output iterator for which `++` is a no-op, `*` returns `*this`, and `=` calls `push_back` on the instantiating container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check what the statements do – there is no magic involved. In particular, `copy` is (essentially) just a loop. Simplified:

```
template <typename I>
void copy(I begin, I end, I target) {
    while (begin != end)
        *target++ = *begin++;
}
```

And [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) really does what the name says.

So in effect, *without* the`back_inserter` you do not expand the target container, you just write past its end: iterators don’t change their underlying container. The `back_inserter` function, on the other hand, creates a specialised iterator which *does* hold a reference to its original container and calls `push_back` when you dereference and assign to it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first one you are giving copy a method of inserting, and from what container to insert from.

In the second one you are only giving a pointer to the end of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Both return iterators, but...

`ret.end()` returns an iterator pointing to the end of the
container.  It can be decremented, but not incremented (since it
already points to the end of the sequence), and it cannot be
dereferenced unless it is decremented (again, because it points
to one past the end of the sequence).

`back_inserter(ret)` is a function which returns
a `back_insertion_iterator`, which is a very special type of
"iterator" (category OutputIterator): it's incrementation
functions are no-ops, dereferencing it returns `*this`, and
assigning a value type to it calls `push_back` on the owning
container.  (In other words, it's not an iterator at all, except
for the C++ standard; but it presents the interface of one to do
something very different.)